# Python, Should I upload my .coverage file to my github repository?

Tags: python, coverage.py

Im using python 3.9 and coverage 6.2

I would like to have a record of my most recent coverage but Im not sure if I should upload my .coverage file. Im guessing no since it sort of has info about my directory layout. So i would like to know how I should go about that, is it even standard to upload such a thing? If not, why not?

I also generated the htmlcov folder but I didnt upload it since it has a default gitignore for the entire folder.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most people don't upload the .coverage or HTML report, because they don't need to track it over time.  But there's no harm in uploading them.  You mention directory layout as if it was a secret to protect, but isn't your layout already committed to GitHub?

If you want to commit the HTML report, you will need to remove the .gitignore file in the directory.

Comment: With the layout I meant the full path of the project within my computer (/home/user/.../program), not just the layout of the project.

Comment: Hmm, I see what you mean, but I'm not sure that's sensitive information that would put you at risk.

Comment: It could be in some cases and I rather not give it away, specially if thats not the standard when unittesting in python

Comment: OK, sounds like you should avoid uploading the coverage data. That's the standard approach anyway.